# scrollTop() lag/scroll resolution issue on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Hi I am writing a web page that has a list of elements (in a UL)

Every 11th element sticks to the top of the page.  So when you scroll up and #11 hits the top of the page it stops. (I actually clone the LI and stick it to the top)

Now when the 22nd element comes up it "pushes" the 11th element up.

Basically I am trying to recreate the iOS headers you see on their address book.

The code uses jQuery and binds to the scroll event of the window.  Then I calculate where the elements are and do the magic.

This all works brilliantly on the desktop (Chrome, Firefox, even IE!).  However when I test it on Chrome on my Galaxy S3 there appears to be a lag when detecting the elements at the top.

My guess is that due to processing power on the mobile devices they do not fire the scroll event as often as it does on desktops.  If you look at this fiddle from another SO post and run it on a mobile device you will see the same problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/YqPzS/

```
function checkScrolling() {

    if ($('#content').scrollTop() > mastheadHeight) {
        menu.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        menu.removeClass('fixed');
    }

}

$('#content').scroll(function () {
    checkScrolling();
});
```

Also a jquery plugin that tries to do the same thing has similar problems.  Take a look at the demo on this page

http://www.teamdf.com/web/showcasing-jquery-list-with-a-fake-iphone/147/

So is it possible to get the same speed/resolution of scrolling on a mobile device as it is on the desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/). With [winscrolled](https://github.com/suprMax/zepto-winscrolled) to make it easier.